# check if there is something below the last line of a file

Tags: php, linux

I need to check if there is something below the last line. (if you can place the cursor below it, then it should match.)

```
This is the first line
This is the last line
|
```

**Note**: The `|` below `This is the last line` represents that there is a empty line below the last line, so you can place your cursor below the last line.

How can i detect this? I tried it with `preg_match`, but a solution with linux commands would also be fine.

https://regex101.com/r/mY9wQ3/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with a regex:
It checks for 2 consecutive EOL at the end of the text buffer, in all possible variants.

### Code

```
<?php

// The function ----------------------------------------------------------
function hasEOLatEnd($text) {
    return (preg_match('/.*?(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n){2,2}$/s', $text));
} 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Tests -----------------------------------------------------------------
$text_1 = "This a one line - without EOL";
$text_2 = "This is one line - with EOL
";
$text_3 = "These are two lines - 
without EOL";
$text_4 = "These are two lines - 
with EOL
";

echo '$text_1 has ' . (hasEOLatEnd($text_1) ? 'EOL' : 'NO EOL') . ' at the end<br />';
echo '$text_2 has ' . (hasEOLatEnd($text_2) ? 'EOL' : 'NO EOL') . ' at the end<br />';
echo '$text_3 has ' . (hasEOLatEnd($text_3) ? 'EOL' : 'NO EOL') . ' at the end<br />';
echo '$text_4 has ' . (hasEOLatEnd($text_4) ? 'EOL' : 'NO EOL') . ' at the end<br />';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

?>
```

### Result

> ```
> $text_1 has NO EOL at the end
> $text_2 has EOL at the end
> $text_3 has NO EOL at the end
> $text_4 has EOL at the end
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Do `tail -n1 <filename> | grep '^$'` -- this will return 0 if the last line of the file is empty.

Comment: This does not seem to work, it does not return 0. I tried it with a file with no empty line at end and with a file with empty line at end, the result is always the same.

Comment: That's interesting. How are you checking the return code? What platform are you doing this on? It works for me on both OSX and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
function no_space_after($str){
     return (trim($str) == $str);
}
```